# Expression Type (imageNamed: String) is ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Can you help me? What can be the issue?
Here is the full code!

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

var bird = SKSpriteNode()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    //Physics
    self.physicsWorld.gravity=CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: -5.0);

    //Bird
    let BirdTextures = (imageNamed:  "bird") //Expression Type(imageNamed: String) is ambiguous without more context.
    BirdTextures.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest

    bird = SKSpriteNode(texture : BirdTextures)
    bird.setScale(0.5)
    bird.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width * 0.35, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.6)
```

Comment: Where's the classname?

Comment: FYI - variable names should start with lowercase letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let BirdTextures = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bird")
```

[Change it to something more meaningful](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sktexture/1520086-init)

Comment: Looking at how it is used in later code, it should probably be `SKTexture`.

Comment: Yes, it’s the SKTexture! Thx for help :)

Comment: The “meaningfull” wasn’t the most understandable answer that i ever get, but at the end i knew ehat you mean :D :P